# raspberry pi 3B+ using BCM2835 lib to generate Hareware PWM (send specific numbers of pulses)

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, pwm

I am working on using Raspberry Pi to generate hardware PWM to control my stepper motors. When I tried hardware pwm, I found that I can not control the pulse in numbers such as I just wanted motor to move 8000 steps and then stop.

I don't want use time to turn off the PWM, I want specific steps.

```
#include <bcm2835.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// PWM output on RPi Plug P1 pin 12 (which is GPIO pin 18)
// in alt fun 5.
// Note that this is the _only_ PWM pin available on the RPi IO headers
#define PIN RPI_GPIO_P1_12
// and it is controlled by PWM channel 0
#define PWM_CHANNEL 0
// This controls the max range of the PWM signal
#define RANGE 1024

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (!bcm2835_init())
    return 1;

    // Set the output pin to Alt Fun 5, to allow PWM channel 0 to be output there
    bcm2835_gpio_fsel(PIN, BCM2835_GPIO_FSEL_ALT5);

    // Clock divider is set to 16.
    // With a divider of 16 and a RANGE of 1024, in MARKSPACE mode,
    // the pulse repetition frequency will be
    // 1.2MHz/1024 = 1171.875Hz, suitable for driving a DC motor with PWM
    bcm2835_pwm_set_clock(BCM2835_PWM_CLOCK_DIVIDER_16);
    bcm2835_pwm_set_mode(PWM_CHANNEL, 1, 1);   //CTL reg
    bcm2835_pwm_set_range(PWM_CHANNEL, RANGE); //RNG1/2 reg

    // Vary the PWM m/s ratio between 1/RANGE and (RANGE-1)/RANGE
    int direction = 1;
    int data = 1;
    while (1)
      {
    if (data == 1)
      direction = 1;
    else if (data == RANGE-1)
      direction = -1;
    data += direction;
      bcm2835_pwm_set_data(PWM_CHANNEL, data);
    bcm2835_delay(1);
      }

    bcm2835_close();
    return 0;
}
```

Can this code achieve my thought (modifying some registers of pwm)? Which reg of PWM control the autofill(autopadding), I just want to know how to stop sending pulses after stopping the motor.